# In what way are union types better for correctness than a common interface?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, f#

I've just recently started familiarising myself with functional programming, mostly via F#, and there's one particular functional idiom that I'm not fully understanding the benefits of. I've seen it described in a few places, but I'll refer to the version [in this article](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-for-correctness/).

The article describes a shopping cart with several requirements, which essentially put it in one of three states: `Empty`, `Active` (occupied by one or more items but not yet paid for), or `PaidFor`. It's argued that by using F#, it's easy to ensure correctness because the compiler will prevent you from performing illegal operations on cart states. For example:

```
let addItemToCart cart item =  
   match cart with
   | Empty state -> state.Add item
   | Active state -> state.Add item
   | PaidFor state ->  
       printfn "ERROR: The cart is paid for"
       cart
```

Only the `Empty` and `Active` states have `Add` methods attached, so if we tried to instead write:

```
| PaidFor state -> state.Add item
```

or similar, we'd get a compiler error.

By comparison, an OO approach might (in C#) look like:

```
interface ICart
{
    ICart AddItem(CartItem item);
}

class EmptyCart : ICart
{
    public ICart AddItem(CartItem item)
    {
        return new ActiveCart(item);
    }
}

class ActiveCart : ICart
{
    public ICart AddItem(CartItem item)
    {
        return new ActiveCart(_items.Add(item));
    }
}

class PaidForCart : ICart
{
    public ICart AddItem(CartItem item)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Who cares about Liskov anyway?");
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to understand is what benefit a client gets from having `addItemToCart` rather than `ICart.AddItem`. Either way, there's no compile-time check stopping the client from using that function with a paid for cart. And either way, the client has no control over what happens in the error case.

The functional version could be modified to give some control to the client over what happens in the error case (a callback, or some wrapper type over the result), but the object-oriented could be modified to do so just as easily (maybe with a `TryAddItem` method, which would be a bit more OO-idiomatic).

So what am I missing?

**Edit**

It was mentioned that in the comments that in the C# version, anyone could create an `ICart` implementation. To address that: an alternative version would be to replace `ICart` with an abstract `Cart` class and make its constructors internal. This isn't ideal and in some situations may not be feasible, but I think in the general case it works pretty well.

Comment: From the article, the compile time error is for paying, which is arguably the dangerous operation. What's more, your C# code isn't equivalent because an interface allows infinite implementations; you can't add new classes to the F# Cart type, ensuring that you only ever deal with the three cases. The equivalent C# code would have to use an abstract class with a private constructor and sealed inner subclasses to simulate the finite number of alternatives, and a visitor to safely determine which which alternative you're dealing with. It gets verbose/ugly really, really fast.

Comment: Note that interfaces and union types have dual properties. An interface makes it easy to introduce new alternatives (the implementing classes) but you have to keep the interface methods fixed, and you can't inspect other instances of the interface. With a union type the alternatives are fixed but adding new functions isn't a problem, and you can have binary functions that look at the fields of two instances of the union type.

Comment: @Doval I understand that the two aren't *exactly* equivilent, but I'm not sure how this is relevant to the point. So what if somebody could add more `ICart` implementations? What's the problem? And the point of my question is that I *don't* see why the Visitor-type approach (which is much closer to a literal translation of the functional version) is any better than the naive OO approach I described in the question.

Comment: How will you prove your eShop software does the right thing *every time* when anyone can make a bogus `ICart` that doesn't remove items when requested, or adds items three times, or lets you pay for carts that have already been paid? The naive OO approach you presented leaves much more room for error, which is bad when correctness is *critical*, and the Visitor approach is much more cumbersome.

Comment: Won't the `Add` blow up at compile time in the F# version? A better implementation in C# would be to have two interfaces, one with `Add` and one without.

Comment: @Doval In the functional version somebody could easily make a function called `add` which actually removes. Would that be correct? In the naive OO version, nobody who has an instance of an `EmptyCart` could call a method on it and end up with a `MaliciousCart`, because no instance of `EmptyCart` returns a `MaliciousCart`. So yes, if somebody implemented an entirely new set of classes using the same interface I exposed, that new set of classes would be wrong. But "only expose interfaces that nobody could ever implement incorrectly" seems like an insane criteria for correctness.

Comment: @Telastyn Not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @BenAaronson - `IMutableCart` implements `ICart`. `EmptyCart` and `ActiveCart` implement `IMutableCart`, but `PaidForCart` only implements `ICart`. That would better match the union type as I understand it (and you describe it).

Comment: @Telastyn You're probably correct, and in fact a visitor pattern (or a version where `Func`s are passed as further down in that article) would be a more accurate translation of the functional version. But my question isn't how to translate functional idioms, it's asking what advantage the functional version provides over the OO version in terms of correctness

Comment: @BenAaronson In the naive OO version, if you accept an `ICart` you don't know that it's actually an `EmptyCart` and not a `MaliciousCart`. You could break the abstraction and check with `is`, but then you're adding a lot of work for yourself and the best you can do is blow up at runtime. If you don't want to get a `MaliciousCart`s, then don't let people make them in the first place. And yes, you can screw up the `add` method in F# if you really want, but you could screw up an `ICart` just as easily, and you can make the F# Cart type abstract so people have to go through your `add` function.

Comment: @Doval I agree with that last sentence, I'm certainly not trying to argue that the functional version is any *worse*, I'm just trying to understand why it's *better*. And I see your point with a consumer of `ICart` wanting to know the possible types, though I think realistically a system that consumes `ICart` would probably itself instantiate an `EmptyCart`, since it's a domain object. And even if it didn't, that comparison still feels a bit like sleight of hand. In either version it's equally possible for the consumer to get a function that doesn't do what it says it does

Comment: @Doval By the way, you could probably scrape those comments together into an answer if you wanted!

Comment: @BenAaronson I'll probably do so at some point later in the day. Also, to address your edit - replacing the interface with a class is only impractical in some situations because C# and Java insist that every class must have a globally-unique identifier, essentially forcing you to hard-code references to classes. Languages like Standard ML and Ocaml have more powerful module systems that don't impose such restrictions on you, letting you swap one implementation for another as long as they have the same API. Java/C# use interfaces and dependency injection as a band-aid for this.

Comment: @BenAaronson - Well it kinda matters. If the C# version that does the same thing is a lot more awkward, or the idiomatic C# version allows more incorrect usage past the compiler, it changes the answer to your question.

Comment: @Telastyn "the idiomatic C# version allows more incorrect usage past the compiler" Well this is what I'm asking about. See in particular the paragraph immediately after the final code block

Comment: ADTs are closed types, that's the real difference. You can do closed types in C# too, see http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2012/01/encoding-algebraic-data-types-in-c.html

Answer (score 6):

There *is* no benefit from from having `addItemToCart` rather than `ICart.AddItem`.  They are essentially identical.  Both of those necessarily have a runtime check, because you want to be able to have a variable with any kind of `Cart` in it, and you won't know at compile time which one will get passed into the function.

Where the benefit comes is when you first implement `addItemToCart`, or later when you add another operation at the same level of abstraction, say `oneClickAddAndPay`.  The union type will give you a compile error if you try to `Add` an item to a `PaidFor` cart, or if you completely forget to account for `PaidFor` carts at all.  The `ICart` interface can't catch that kind of programming error at compile time.

In other words, the union type can't move all kinds of errors to compile time, but it does move *some*.  If you don't end up adding a lot of functions like `oneClickAddAndPay` that reuse the existing `Add` functionality, it won't buy you much.

Comment: This is a good point. But comparing like for like, I'm still not exactly sure I see the benefit. When I implement the empty cart case in `addItemToCart`, I do it in the `match` statement. When I implement it for `ICart.AddItem`, I do it in the body of `EmptyCart.AddItem`. Why is one of those any safer than the other?

Comment: You're not implementing the entire empty cart case in the `match` expression.  Part of it is in the `match` expression, and part of it is in the `addToEmptyState` function.  You have two layers of abstraction instead of one, and calls from the upper to the lower can now be type checked at compile time.  Like I said, it doesn't buy you much unless you do a lot more work in the upper layer than the example shows.

Answer (score 2):

In your example I see no benefit, but other languages (like [Ceylon](http://ceylon-lang.org/)) use union types in useful ways. Imagine doing something like this (C#)

```
int Length<A> (String | List<A> obj) {...}
```

While this example isn't very meaningful since String implements IEnumerable, the idea behind this is that you can receive a parameter which can be one various type, use the fields/properties/methods those types have in common naturally, and use switch/case when type dependent behavior is needed.

In F# I guess you could create some helper types to accomplish little things like this. I prefer the Ceylon way: Polymorphism + (mainly anonymous) Union Types.

Union Types can help a lot for correctness if you assume that `null` is the only instance of type `Null`, then if you want to declare that something can be `null` you should use the type `T | Null` or its abbreviation `T?`.